# RFID reader without micro-controller

Tags: rfid

I wanted to build a RFID reader without using any micro-controller or chips or Arduino.
But everywhere on the internet, I find that these are used in the circuit.
Is there any way I can make one without using these?
If yes, can anyone please explain how?

Comment: How do you imagine that you would use the data obtained from such a reader?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done with a rack of discrete transistors, resistors, capacitors, and other components.  After all, that's what's in the chips you don't want to use.

While it *can* be done, it would be very tedious, expensive, difficult to get running, and large.

Even if the reason is to avoid learning about chips and microcontrollers, this still doesn't make sense.  You have to know a lot more about analog electronics to design the control circuitry with discrete parts.  Learning all that, building this thing, and then debugging it would take longer than learning to use microcontrollers and those "chips" you want to avoid.

The whole concept is, frankly, completely silly.

Answer (score 1):

The RFID interface will provide you information on the **digital domain**. Unless you buy an end product with, lets say, Wi-Fi and a web interface, you cannot escape that.

**Arduino is not hard to learn.** There are libraries to do complex stuff and loads of example code. When you're done prototyping you can buy one of those prototyping PCBs (idk the exact name of them) and solder a socket and put the chip in there. The only extra components you will need are a capacitor between the power rails of the micro-controller and optionally an external oscillator with two capcitors.

If you configure the Arduino to use it's internal oscillator, you'll only need the chip and one capacitor (plus power supply).

Answer (score 0):

No.

RFID is a means of transmitting digital information using radio-frequency transmission. You may be able to sense presence of an RFID tag with analog transistor circuitry and a suitable antenna but you won't be able to decode the digital information.